# Can't change style value on second page using DataTable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, spring

At the first Page I can see negative value (e.g. -11) being changed to red.

However, when I clicked to the second page, negative value didn't change to red.

My code as below:

```
$("#listReport").DataTable({
    'aoColumnDefs': [{
        'bSortable': false,
        'aTargets': [-1]
    }]

});

$('#listReport tbody td').each(function (index) {
    var qtyvalue = $(this).html();
    if (qtyvalue < 0) {
        $(this).wrapInner('<strong style="color:red"></strong>');
    }
});
```

Any idea what to change in my code so that pagination works well with color change of the negative values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`columns.render`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) instead of manually trying to do it. Try this

```
$("#listReport").DataTable({
    'aoColumnDefs': [
        {
            'bSortable': false,
            'aTargets': [-1]
        },{
            'targets': [1], // target column
            "data": 1, // column index
            "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
                if( type === 'display' ){
                    return '<strong style="color:red">'+data+'</strong>';
                }

                return data;
            }
        }
    ]
});
```